# Permalink issues with Ubuntu Server - Infinite loop & Wrong pages

Tags: permalinks

I'm having a big problem with Permalinks on our Wordpress installation.
It's currently running Ubuntu 10.4 and when i add a page to the site, there are odd things happening:

1. We get infinite loop and "too many redirect" warnings from different browsers
2. Other links on the site get redirected to the newly created page 
   For example, after creating a page with the URL of "/promolanding/" when someone clicks on the link to the "/about-us/" page, it redirects them to "/promolanding/"

This works fine on my CentOS development server and only happens on the Ubuntu server.

Permalinks are set to:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

and the .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Has anyone ever had this issue?  If so, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is if working fine with default permalink? e.g. `p=234`

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using, have you clicked save permalinks under settings? Does your server have mod-rewrite installed?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the server version, most likely it is related to apache modules and/or version.

Comment: @steven, Yes... it works with Default.

Comment: @wyck... yes, mod_rewrite is installed and I have Apache 2.2.14 installed.  The major concern is that it works for some, but not for others.

Comment: @wyck - I'm using wordpress 3.2.1.  My server guy keeps telling me it's Wordpress, but this works fine on the CentOS server and not on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks everyone for helping out with this, but it looks like the issue was the canonical redirects in wordpress conflicting with the server.

I fixed the problem by adding this to my functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

I've never ran into this issue before, but this is the first time I've ever worked with Ubuntu, so it's a learning experience.

Cheers!
Troy

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this bug before with the redirection plugin.  To rule out any theme or plugin issues disable all your plugins switch to the Twentyten or Twentyeleven theme and flush your permalinks.  Also make sure there are no other .htaccess files in any of the other WordPress directories or other rules in your vhost file.

I've used Debian / Ubuntu Apache 2.2.14 package on many different servers with no issues.

Comment: Hi Chris, the problem is I don't have any redirection plugin installed... That was the first thing I removed and haven't had it on there since.  After I removed it... I did what you had listed above, switched to a different theme and flushed my rules, but it kept happening.  I'm thinking it may be something with the settings on the server, but I'm still looking.  Thanks!